# Code navigation for remote server in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have installed visual code in my mac to be able to access code to a remote server. I have installed remote-ssh and python packages for vs code and I have managed to connect remotely to my projects in server. However, my issue is while I can use python code navigation locally, I cannot do it in the server. Any ideas why?

Do I need to do any configuration in the remote server?

Comment: If you're using the remote extensions for VS Code it should all just work transparently if the files are a part of your workspace.

Comment: I am opening a project from the remote-server. When I use the VS Code in the server I can navigate properly in the code. When I am using a local project on my laptop the same. But when I am trying to connect with remote-ssh from laptop to the server, navigation do not work.

Comment: If by "remote-ssh" you mean https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh then you may need to open an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) extension is installed on your remote extensions or not. I used to stick to this problem once so by installing the Pylance my problem was solved.